# Make sure item is delivered to onNext listener in RxJava

Tags: collections, synchronization, rx-java

I've a specific need to make sure item is delivered to the subscriber. It would be nice if `onNext` will return `boolean` indicating whether the item has been delivered or not, but it unfortunately returns `void`.

I've collection of items which are backed by `BlockingDeque`. New items are added to the queue and pooled by subscribers. Subscriber may unsubscribe at any time and the item may be lost. Here's my current implementation:

```
return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Item> subscriber) -> {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Item item = items.poll(poolTimeout, poolUnit);
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext(item);
            } else {
                items.addFirst(item);
                break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    subscriber.onCompleted();
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   ...
```

Even though I'm checking `isUnsubscribed` before calling `onNext` there may be situation when `Subscriber` has unsubscribed between the check and item delivery. It's common synchronization problem and it's easy to test, for example sometimes my test fails with `AssertionError` when checking for received collection size

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected size:<1000> but was:<999> in:
```

I'm looking for solution that allows me to deliver items in FIFO order with 100% certainty that no item is lost. Any ideas how to achieve this in RxJava?

Comment: You want to emit an item event if you have unsubscribe ?

Comment: @dwursteisen No. I want to emit items when somebody is subscribed and be sure the item has been processed. Currently there may be lost items when subscriber unsubscribed during `subscriber.onNext(item)` handling. That's why only 999 items are delivered and 1 is lost.

Comment: You could add a consumed flag to the item and see if it is true after calling onNext.

Comment: @akarnokd I doubt it's correct solution. Publishing and subscribing is performed on different threads, you want to publish all the items as fast as possible on one thread and handle them on another thread separately. Checking if the item has been consumed on the publishing thread doesn't make sense for me, do I miss something important in your solution?

Comment: Do you send off the item to be processed asynchronously and you want to wait for it synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need a guaranteed end-to-end delivery with the option to piggyback on rejected items due unsubscription?

Unfortunately, RxJava is not architected this way since many operators and classes simply drop onNext values after they unsubscribed. I see some problems as well:

- Which subscriber can tell if the item was consumed successfully?
- `boolean onNext(T t)` doesn't compose well across async boundaries. We had a similar problem with unsubscription.
- returning boolean implies the need to block if downstream uses observeOn.

I can only imagine a setup where there is a concurrent set of items. The source places an item into this set and calls onNext. The final subscriber, when successfully processed the item, removes this item from the set. If this final subscriber unsubscribes, all remaining items can be considered undelivered. Note however, that unsubscription is best effort so the set may indicate undelivered events that will be successfully delivered in a short time after unsubscription, unless you synchronize onNext and an unsubscription action. [Here is an example code](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/cfeca37ba8b2bea4e8a8).

Comment: I will check the code and let you know if it fits my needs